# Datetimepicker for ham fingered employees :)

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

Has anyone found a decent datetimepicker that works for touch based applications?,mainly the calendar that pops up when selected. 
Or have another idea of a way i can capture dates/date ranges utilizing touch inputs with a better UI experience.

Background:
i have an app at work which uses a windows tablet with rfid reader for staff to log in and out and other simple tasks, i have added to ability for them to book holiday via the same device, effectively making it paperless and eliminate the admin of holiday as much as possible. this works perfectly but the calendar is just a bit to small for touch inputs.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Sadly this question can potentially have many opinionated answers instead a few objective ones and most likely it will be flagged for closing as opinion-based.

Comment: I wonder if there is a date picker that allows zooming using the touch based screen. IMHO that would be very usable in your app.